# Work wants to create an admin account on my system that I don't have access to?

Tags: windows, privacy, access-control, corporate-policy, monitoring

This is on a Windows 10 system, and they want to create an administrator account that only my manager will have the password to. This is apparently to enforce some new "security policies" that haven't really been explained. This isn't from IT, I already have administrator access and it's a small company.

To me it seems like there's a couple of possibilities

- To create a backdoor to RDP and/or install monitoring software.
- Gain access to my files remotely or while I'm away.
- Potentially have a way to reclaim the computer if I were to leave

Am I completely off base here? What access does creating a secondary administrator account provide them? Is there anything I should be doing to secure my privacy and data? I only log into one account for streaming music, and have 2FA.

Also, after I bring my laptop home, is there any possibility for them to access my personal computers and is it legal?

Comment: This question is too vague to answer because you mainly offer some ideas based on your lack of information: "...that haven't really been explained...".  Also it is not clear if "my system" is a system fully owned by you or a system owned by your employer. And if such things are legal or not will vary depending on the exact environment and is off-topic here anyway.

Comment: Probably better suited for [workplace.se]. But in essence, if the computer belongs to the company, suck it up. And I'd recommend in any case to go to IT and ask more details info of what is the intention.

Comment: Yeah, jurisdiction and whether it's your PC or a work one are important. Also, are you expected to do work remotely/from home?

Comment: Just to be clear, do you own the computer, or do they own it? That is very important for the answer to this question.